# Unable to Activate Excel Window

Tags: c#, asp.net, office-interop

The Excel Window stays minimized. How can I bring this to the front of the browser.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

protected void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  OpenExcel();
}

private void OpenExcel()
{
  Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
  Excel.Workbook wb = null;
  Excel.Worksheet ws = null;
  Excel.Range range = null;

  app.visible = true;
  wb = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
   ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.WorkSheets[1];
   range = ws.get_Range("A1","D1");

   ws.Cells[1,1]="Date";
   ws.Cells[1,2]="Code";
   ws.Cells[1,3]="Name";
   app.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlNormal;     
   app.ActiveWindow.Activate();
}
```

Comment: If you do this in ASP.Net then it won't be able to work with the same instance as the one you currently have open on your desktop. Even if you run this on the same computer they will work with different instances of Excel.

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Answer (score 3):

In order to guarantee this, in my experience, I had to do the following:

```
if (app.WindowState == XlWindowState.xlMinimized)
{
    app.WindowState = XlWindowState.xlNormal;
}
app.WindowState = XlWindowState.xlMaximized;
app.ShowWindowsInTaskbar = true;
app.Visible = true;

IntPtr hwnd = new IntPtr(app.Hwnd);
Win32Helper.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
```

SetForegroundWindow is interop

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Comment: I would not recommend doing COM interop in ASP.NET.

Comment: But that's the question you just answered.